# Lucene custom QueryParser no results

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I've subclassed QueryParser in Apache Lucene to change input field name (user reuqest) to corresponding field name in my model class.

```
public class QueryParserMoney extends QueryParser {

public QueryParserMoney(Version matchVersion, String f, Analyzer a) {
    super(matchVersion, f, a);

}

@Override
protected Query newTermQuery(Term term) {
    if (term.field() == "money") {
        PaddedIntegerBridge pB = new PaddedIntegerBridge();

        TermRangeQuery trq = new TermRangeQuery("moneyTo",
        pB.objectToString(Integer.parseInt(term.text())), "*",
                true, true);

        return trq;

    }
    return super.newTermQuery(term);
}
```

the input query is like `money:5000` and i'm changing it to `moneyTo:[5000 TO *]`
generated query is ok, I'm checking query with Luke, but in Java I have 0 results.

Have you any suggestions where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `moneyTo` a numeric field? If so, you should use NumericRangeQuery instead of TermRangeQuery. If `moneyTo` is a string field, it does not look like TermRangeQuery recognizes "*" as an open endpoint, and you should use `null` instead.

Comment: but why generated query works correctly in Luke?
and moneyTo is numeric field

Comment: I'll try your suggestions today morning and I'll give response if it will work

Comment: Are you using your subclass of QueryParser in Luke, not the built-in/default QueryParser?

Comment: I'm just using `moneyTo:[5000 TO *]` in field search in Luke and it works

Comment: The output of `Query.toString()` is not necessarily a complete representation of the query.  You can't expect to do something like `QueryParser.parse(query.toString());` and get the same query back.  YOu are seeing exactly that.  The query parser takes "*" for an open ended range, but for a manually constructed query, it will be the term "*".